# Why the following PHP code is not inserting the values in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert the values of a form into the database table called company. But this program again and again tells me that my query did not get executed. May I know why this is so??

I have stored all the values of the form into an array called insert and than I implode the array and name it as newarray so that it is in a form which can be inserted into the database.

But this does not seem to work for me. Please tell me what's the problem in here??

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$name = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "shopinz";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$name,$password,$db);
$insert = array();
$newarray = array();
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo("Cannot connect to the databse".mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}
else{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        foreach($_POST as $value){
            if($value == $_POST['submit']){
                break;
            } 
            else{
                    array_push($GLOBALS['insert'],$value);
            }
        }
         $newarray = implode(',',$insert);
         $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO company (company_name,company_number,company_address) VALUES($newarray)");
         if($result){
             echo("1 row added");
         }
         else{
             echo("Query not executed");
         }
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Why don't you look at the query you are actually running? Why don't you use `mysqli_error()` to find out what the database is saying about your attempt to run the code?

Comment: Output all errors. Your values are not encapsulated with `"` in `$newarray` and that produces wrong SQL code

Comment: print_r the $newarray var and see what is returned. I ssupect it is empty as a result of the break statement when the submit button is bresent.

Comment: `array_push($GLOBALS['insert'],$value);` permission to cry.

Comment: somehow php always attracts people to write code that way

Comment: I used mysqli_error() and it gives me error  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters

Answer (score 1):

This line has no significance:

```
array_push($GLOBALS['insert'],$value);
```

Push your values to the one that you need which is `$insert`

```
unset($_POST['submit']);
foreach($_POST as $value){
    $insert[] = "'".$con->real_escape_string($value)."'";
}
$newarray = implode(',',$insert);
```

Note: I suggest use prepared statements instead.

```
$insert = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO company (company_name,company_number,company_address) VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
$insert->bind_param('sss', $_POST['company_name'], $_POST['company_number'], $_POST['company_address']);
$insert->execute();
```

Answer (score -3):

Looking at your code the problem I can see is here:

```
 foreach($_POST as $value){
```

In your foreach you have $_POST but you dont define what posit it si it should be $_POST['something']

Comment: `$_POST` is always defined... http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: I am only trying to help if the answer is incorrect you cann point me to a source where I can learn... like @NDM did...